# Hide targets when configure is run with certain options

Tags: makefile, configure, autotools

My configure.ac lets the user specify `--enable-monitor`. In a subdirectory, I have a Makefile.in which contains a certain number of targets to build. I would like some of them to be only available when the user has specified `--enable-monitor`

Put differently, I want the user to be only able to run `make monitor` when `./configure` has been run with `--enable-monitor`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be sufficient to put this in `configure.ac`:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE([monitor],[help string],[use_monitor=yes])
AM_CONDITIONAL([USE_MONITOR],[test "$use_monitor" = yes])
```

and this in Makefile.am:

```
if USE_MONITOR
bin_PROGRAMS = monitor
else
monitor:
    @echo Target not supported >&2 && exit 1
endif
```

The else clause with an explicit monitor target is used to override and default rules that Make might otherwise use.  Note that "help string" ought to be more useful and constructed using `AS_HELP_STRING`, but those details have been omitted for brevity.

--EDIT--

Since automake is not being used, you can replace the `AM_CONDITIONAL` line in configure.ac with something like:

```
AC_SUBST([USE_MONITOR],[$use_monitor])
```

and then do checks in `Makefile.in` like:

```
monitor:
        @if test "@USE_MONITOR@" = yes; then \
            ... ; \
        else \
            echo Target not supported >&2 && exit 1; \
        fi
```

Comment: That would be perfect if I used automake, but my question stated "Makefile.in", because I don’t. Is there anything comparable without using Automake?